# Brew Doctor changing directories

Tags: terminal, directory, homebrew

I'm very new to this and I'm currently installing all the needed programs that I need for my online courses.

I've come to homebrew / brew doctor now and whenever I try to type "`brew doctor`" into the terminal I get the following:

```
Some directories in your path end in a slash.
Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other
doctor checks. The following directories should be edited:
    ./
```

I've tried looking around but this is the first I've seen where there's not a specific directory mentioned, only *    ./*

How do I fix this?

Edit:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/ME/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/bin‌​:/usr/local/mysql/bin:./:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bi‌​n
```

Edit 2: And how do I edit my login profile? I'm sorry if this is extremely obvious, but I am extremely new at this.

Edit 3:

```
$HOME/.profile -bash: /Users/ME/.profile: No such file or directory
```

Edit 4: `grep PATH ~/.bash_profile` gives:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:./:$PATH"
```

Edit 5: Thanks for pointing out the error, greatly appreciated. How do I remove that from my PATH?

Edit 6, hopefully last. Thank you all so far: typed in: `$HOME/.bash_profile`

```
-bash: /Users/ME/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

Comment: Try `echo $PATH` and see if you can see what it is referring to - then edit your login profile... `$HOME/.profile` probably.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button under your question to bring your question to the latest version and to add additional information. That said, can you give us the output of `grep PATH ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: You have `./` in your PATH. Edit your $HOME/.bash_profile` and change it to `.`

Comment: @MarkSetchell You should write this as an answer.